# Telegram bot how to make answering to the questions via nltk python

Tags: python, nltk, telegram-bot, chatbot

I tried using nltk library. And reached till FreqDist.And I got FreqDist for the asked question is .2,.5. After this how can I relate this freqDist Value to make bot responsive to the required answer of that asked question?

Comment: have you tokenized  the text to sentences?

Comment: yes i did same, but after that ?